# Loading display while uploading file

Tags: javascript, file-upload

So I got a loading screen when loading a page. That works great. My issue is when i upload files I don't want my user to be able to trigger any other events that may reload the page as the file is uploading.

Can I re-use my loading div whilst the files are uploading.

My javascript is very novice.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<div id="loading"></div>

<!-- Loading --> 
<script>
  function onReady(callback) {
    var intervalID = window.setInterval(checkReady, 1000);

    function checkReady() {
      if (document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0] !== undefined) {
        window.clearInterval(intervalID);
        callback.call(this);
      }
    }
  }

  function show(id, value) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = value ? 'block' : 'none';
  }

  onReady(function () {
    show('loading', false);
  });
</script>
```

Got some source code here: http://xeroharm.com.au/Test.html

Comment: Just call the `show` function..

Comment: Where would I and how would i call it? I did add some source.

Comment: Just `show('loading', false);`

Comment: Where would I call that so it runs when the upload file is selected?

Comment: In the `change` handler of `input-type-file`

Comment: <input type="file" name="Attachment<?php echo $i; ?>" id="Attachment<?php echo $i; ?>" onchange="this.form.submit(); show('loading', false);"/>

Comment: Once you submit the form, page is unloaded and control of the page is lost..

Comment: I already got a form submit. I dont think I can do this

Comment: You can not do DOM manipulations once page is unloaded...